# SQL Left Join match first

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query, in which I have to join Table A and Table B and get the records based on the condition. For example my query looks like below I want to edit this query in such a way that it produces output as shown below..

```
Select A.ID, B.Name
FROM Table A
LEFT JOIN Table b on A.UserID = B.UserID
WHERE ID = 1
```

Table A

```
ID  USERID

 1   10
 1   11
 2   12
```

TABLE B

```
  USERID   Name     IsActive

    10      a        Y
    11      b        NULL
    12      C        NULL
```

So I have to check in my query if the record with IsActive 'Y' exists then use that name otherwise use other name.

How to write query for that

My output should be:

```
   ID   Name

    1     a
    2     C
```

Comment: question is not clear, can you please add more details

Comment: Still unclear. Your first query is not complied with last result.

Comment: yes, first query is not working. I want to edit it in such a way so that it produces the last result.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
Select A.ID,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN IsActive = 'Y' THEN B.Name END), MAX(B.Name)) as Name
FROM Table A LEFT JOIN
     Table b 
     ON A.UserID = B.UserID
WHERE ID = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

By being a little cryptic on your posted question leaves many with questions...  Try not to do so in the future, but offer realistic data to get point across.  You can make up names and such to protect private info, but at least proper context will help.

It LOOKs like your second table "B" represents multiple people... maybe like A is a list of accounts IDs, and B may be a list of people who were working with the given A account.  And when someone leaves and are no longer active, you want whoever the most active contact person is in B table.  If there is no active person in B table, you want the name of the last person who did.

This too implies that there would only ever be a single "Y" record for a given "B" table record for a given user.  Also, what happens if there are multiple NULL "B" records for a given ID.  How would you want the name selected?

In either case, I would do with TWO left-joins.  One with the qualifier of "Y" status, the other without.  Then apply a coalesce() looking first for the "Y" entry, otherwise fall-through to the NULL entry.

```
Select 
      a.ID, 
      max( coalesce( b.Name, b2.Name )) FinalName
   FROM 
      TableA a
         LEFT JOIN TableB b 
            on a.UserID = b.UserID
            and b.IsActive = 'Y'
         LEFT JOIN TableB b2
            on a.UserID = b2.UserID
            and b2.IsActive is null
   WHERE 
      a.ID = 1
   group by
      a.ID
```

So the above will give the respective answer output you are looking for.  It will work, but your sample data is brief and lacking clarification as I have so noted in my answer.

For the future too, if you have comments or clarifications, please EDIT your existing original posted question to add if it is longer than a simple answer.  it will help bring context into original question for others looking for similar, or offering to help answer.

Comment: Perfect explanation. I was looking for the same.If there are multiple NULL "B" records for a given ID, then it can take any of the records. But your query is not working it's giving result as 1, a; 1,b; 1,c

Comment: @user1104946, revised to add group by so it would only grab 1 record per ID.  If a record with "Y" exists, but still should clarify what you have / need because this is a very specific query that probably will not be accurate long-term.